# How can you debug "add to home screen" on Chrome on android?

Tags: android, google-chrome, homescreen, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to add an internal web application to the homescreen of an android device for testing. This should be as a real chrome-wrapped web app with full screen, custom icon, etc.

But it doesn't work, and I see no ways of debugging/troubleshooting the problem.

The manifest is added and linked. The server is on an IP address, non-standard port and with a self-signed SSL certificate - could any if these details be the problem?

Any help on getting this to work, would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I’m having similar problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of ways that you can test to see if you have the configuration correct.

- Use Mounir Lamouri's [Manifest Validator](http://mounirlamouri.github.io/manifest-validator/) to see if there are any obvious errors
- Check Chrome Dev tools.

  - Chrome will always attempt to download the manifest and the icons if they are found (via `link rel=manifest`) and you have a service worker
  - If you don't have a service worker, manually do an "add to homescreen" from Chrome on Android (whilst you are connected via USB debugging see `chrome://inspect`) and you will see it fetch the manifest.

[image: manifest being downloaded]

If you don't see the manifest being downloaded then it is very likely that your page is mis-configured so ensure that you have a `<link rel="manifest" href="{url to your manifest}">` in your page

Answer (score 1):

also, be sure to disable "bypass user engagement checks" in [chrome://flags](http://chrome://flags), so you can be sure that you're Chrome browser will always met the conditions that allow installation

[image]